# How to see user's comments in Soundcloud?

Tags: soundcloud

Does anyone knows if you can see the comments a user has made in his [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com) profile? You can see the comments a track has, but I don't know if you can see the comments a user has made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see all of a user's comments by clicking 'View All' in the comment section toward the bottom in the right-hand column (by default it will be the second-to-last item, right before the links to iTunes and Google Play).

You can also go directly to a list of a users comments by going to

`https://soundcloud.com/***user-name***/comments`